Providing Kotlin-Inject dependency with SavedStateHandle parameter
I need to use Kotlin-Inject dependency injection library, currently with Android, but in the future target is to have Multiplatform app (iOS + Android)
I have a FlowController interface:
interface FlowController {
   enum class Type { SINGLE, MULTIPLE, OTHER }
}

Then I have three implementations of this FlowController:

SingleFlowControllerImpl(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): FlowController
MultipleFlowControllerImpl(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): FlowController
OtherFlowControllerImpl(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): FlowController

My Fragments include specific parameter in SavedStateHandle so that DI should be able to decide, which FlowController must be injected at this point of time.
@ViewModelScoped
@Component
abstract class ViewModelComponent(@Component val parent: ApplicationComponent) {
    @Provides
    fun providesFlowController(
        @Assisted savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
        controllers: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards FlowController>
    ): FlowController = controllers.first {
        it.flowType == checkNotNull(savedStateHandle[Keys.FLOW_TYPE])
    }

    @ViewModelScoped
    @IntoSet
    @Provides
    fun SingleFlowControllerImpl.bindIntoSet(): FlowController = this 

    [rest of the bindings]

}

Fragment:
@Inject
class MyFragment(
    createViewModel: (SavedInstanceState) -> MyViewModel,
) : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_my) { {
       private val viewModel by viewModel(createViewModel)
}

/**
 * [viewModels] helper that allows you to pass a single factory function using a [SavedStateHandle].
 */
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.viewModel(crossinline factory: (SavedStateHandle) -> VM): Lazy<VM> =
    viewModels {
        viewModelFactory { addInitializer(VM::class) { factory(createSavedStateHandle()) } }
    }


Viewmodel:
@Inject
class MyViewModel(
    private val flowController: FlowController,
    @Assisted private val savedInstanceState: SavedInstanceState,
) { }

Now I need to inject FlowController provided by the ViewModelComponent into Fragment's ViewModel, but it can not resolve the dependency graph, because it does not know how to provide SavedInstanceState to FlowController
